# Sharepoint 2016 compatibility with MS Office 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, office

We currently have a SharePoint 2013 single farm solution. We also have all our users on MS Office 2013. Prior to this our users were accessing documents within the SP 2013 site using SP 2010 where we had endless problems with accessibility which was determined to be the difference in platforms of SP and MS Office.

My question is will this be an issue going forward? We are moving from SP2013 to SP2019 but the users will be using MS Office 2016 - will we come up against the same issue with the compatibility with opening documents and creating and accessing InfoPath forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infopath has not really changed in years (I think what you had in office2013 is same in office2019 maybe apart from some sec updates that affect the whole office). MS wanted to kill many times but faced backslash from large enterprises that use it a lot. You should not face any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Makes the decision sure.

Comment: Just to confirm - documents from MS Office such as word and excel will open in the client application? (we do not plan moving to 365 for another couple of years)

Comment: Yes the documents will open in client application.

Answer (score 1):

No you won't face compatibility issues as such , since I have been using the same scenario in my current project.

I am working on both SP2016 and SP2019 with MS Office 2016 .

Comment: Thanks Yash. Appreciate the feedback and common experience.

Comment: Just to confirm - documents from MS Office such as word and excel will open in the client application? (we do not plan moving to 365 for another couple of years)